# isRequestedSessionIdValid returning false after successful login

Tags: java, authentication, session, servlets, ldap

I'm implementing LDAP authentication on Java web app, and I'm getting the following:

```
try {
    System.out.println(servletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()); //prints true

    servletRequest.login(lUser, lPassword);//successfully logs in

    System.out.println(servletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()); //prints false

} catch (ServletException se) {
    logger.error("Error authenticating user", se);
    return STATE_INPUT;
}
```

Meaning: login method, successfully executed, renders the session invalid... Anyone knows why this happens and how to fix it?
Asking because later the app validades if servletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid() == true and as shown in the code above the login method makes it false.

Comment: Looks like the LDAP implementation being used is using session fixation prevention. Why exactly is that a problem and why exactly must it be fixed?

Comment: That's a problem because I'm leveraging an internal framework and that framework will later verify if servletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid() evaluates to true and it will throw an exception because it evaluates to false. I'll look into that session fixation prevention stuff... see If I can figure something out. Thank you

Comment: Also, if I invalidate the session and request a new one with servletRequest.getSession(true) it keeps showing as invalid.

Comment: Then just fix that "an internal framework" that it doesn't consider a change in session ID during login as illegal.

Comment: It's added as a dependency, I can't change it. But not sure I followed you there... all the framework does is making sure method javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.isRequestedSessionIdValid() returns true, which it does before login, and doesn't after, even if I change session id or request a new session.

Comment: Yup, if you change session ID during the request then isRequestedSessionIdValid() won't return true after that because the current session ID is different from the originally requested one .. I'm not sure why that is so hard to understand. I guess you're looking in the wrong direction for the solution, or that the "an internal framework" actually needs a bugfix. But this cannot be answered as long as the context of your question is still vague. You really don't want to "fix" isRequestedSessionIdValid() itself .. But the other thing which is apparently relying on it in an incorrect way.

Comment: One way to correctly solve your "real" problem might be to simply explicitly send a redirect to the requested URI immediately after login.